# What is the intermediate field of the splitting filed of $x^6+3$ over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I have worked out that the Galois group of $x^6+3$ should be $S_3$, and let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^6+3$, $w = \frac{1+\alpha^3}{2}$, then $\alpha, w \alpha, w^2 \alpha, -\alpha, -w \alpha, -w^2 \alpha$ are roots of $x^6+3$. The Galois group of it should be $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. Then an obvious intermeidate field is $\mathbb Q(w)$ which is of degree $2$. How should I locate other intermeidate fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be three fields of degree $3$, the fixed fields of the subgroups
of order $2$ in the Galois group $G\cong S_3$. Let $\sigma$ be the Galois
group element mapping $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$. It must have order $2$. Then
$$\sigma(\omega)=\sigma\left(\frac12(1+\alpha^3)
\right)=\frac12(1-\alpha^3)=\omega^2.$$
An element of the fixed field of $\left<\sigma\right>$ is then
$$\omega\alpha+\sigma(\omega\alpha)=\omega\alpha-\omega^2\alpha=\beta_1$$
say. If we choose $\alpha=\exp(\pi i/6)\sqrt[6]3$ then
$$\beta_1=\sqrt[6]3(\exp(5\pi i/6)-\exp(-\pi i/2))$$
etc. Likewise, the other two cubic extensions will be generated by
$\beta_2=\alpha-\omega\alpha$ and $\beta_3=\alpha-\omega^2\alpha$.

Comment: How do we know that the fixed field is actually generated by $\beta_1$? Also, how to locate order $2$ and order $3$ elements? The only way I can think of is to write out all possibilities.

Comment: (i) As the extension has prime degree, we only need one element outside the base field to generate it. (ii) six is a small number; in this case writing out all possibilities is not onerous.